# No mapping exists from DbType UInt64 to a known SqlDbType. Dapper C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a table field(`TotalPrice`) in our SQL Server 2016 database with `numeric(20, 3)` data type.

I used `ulong` type as my C# property type.

```
public ulong TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

When I want to insert a record in my Table the following exception occurred.

> No mapping exists from DbType UInt64 to a known SqlDbType

My C# code to insert a record:

```
const string queryInsertInvoice = @"
INSERT INTO Invoice (CustomerId, Number, TotalPrice, LatestStatusDateTime) 
VALUES (@CustomerId, @Number, @TotalPrice, @LatestStatusDateTime)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

var invoiceId = await dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(queryInsertInvoice, invoice);
```

How can I handle this situation with Dapper 2.0.53 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change TotalPrice type to decimal.

```
public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I would rather use long and rename to TotalPriceInCent and store prices in cent. Just my experience with currency-stuff over the last years.

Answer (score 9):

This is deliberate. SQL Server doesn't have unsigned integers, so it is trying to prevent you from storing the data as something different to what you expected - wraparound is fine for *equality* operations, but inequality operations would behave very unexpectedly for some values if we allowed this.

In other words: use `long`, not `ulong`.

---

Edit: I could be sold on the "Dapper should allow `ulong` for the first 63 bits - coercing it to `long` - and throw and exception (`OverflowException`?) if the MSB is set". That just isn't implemented today.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Dapper what I do is create separate data classes from my main model that represent the results from SQL. With these `SqlModel` classes, I make sure the types align exactly with how things are represented in SQL. In my C# business logic, often it is easier to use `int` or enums for variables where they may be `TINYINT` in SQL. So I would end up with two classes like this:

```
class UserSqlModel {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public byte UserTypeId { get; set; }
}

class User {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public UserType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would write a mapping function between the two models. This isolates your business logic from the nuances of how data is represented in SQL and allows refactoring your business logic or SQL implementation separately.

In your example, maybe your `SqlModel` would have a `long` property and your mapping function would handle conversion of `ulong` to `long` and would deal with overflow issues.